# CUDA finding the max value in given array

Tags: cuda

I tried to develop a small CUDA program for find the max value in the given array,

```
int input_data[0...50] = 1,2,3,4,5....,50
```

`max_value` initialized by the first value of the `input_data[0]`,
The final answer is stored in `result[0]`. 
The kernel is giving 0 as the max value. I don't know what the problem is.
I executed by 1 block 50 threads.

```
__device__ int lock=0;

__global__ void max(float *input_data,float *result)
{
     float max_value = input_data[0];
     int  tid = threadIdx.x;

     if( input_data[tid] > max_value)
     {
         do{} while(atomicCAS(&lock,0,1));
         max_value=input_data[tid];
         __threadfence();
         lock=0;
      }

    __syncthreads();
    result[0]=max_value;  //Final result of max value 
}
```

Even though there are in-built functions, just I am practicing small problems.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to set up a "critical section", but this approach on CUDA can lead to hang of your whole program - try to avoid it whenever possible.

**Why your code hangs?**

Your kernel (`__global__` function) is executed by groups of 32 threads, called *warps*. All threads inside a single warp execute synchronously. So, the warp will stop in your `do{} while(atomicCAS(&lock,0,1))` until *all* threads from your warp succeed with obtaining the lock. But obviously, you want to prevent several threads from executing the critical section at the same time. This leads to a hang.

**Alternative solution**

What you need is a "parallel reduction algorithm". You can start reading here:

- [Parallel prefix sum @ wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum)
- [Parallel Reduction @ CUDA website](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/Data-Parallel_Algorithms.html)
- [NVIDIA's Guide to Reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf)

Comment: ok. Even if it is take long time to execute i am not getting wright  answer. If each tread gets its lock it has to update the max_value but it is not updating. How to solve

Comment: You can use atomicMax. What you do now with critical sections will plainly _not_ work for the reasons I already explained.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has potential race. I'm not sure if you defined the 'max_value' variable in shared memory or not, but both are wrong.

1) If 'max_value' is just a local variable, then each thread holds the local copy of it, which are not the actual maximum value (they are just the maximum value between input_data[0] and input_data[tid]). In the last line of code, all threads write to result[0] their own max_value, which will result in undefined behavior.

2) If 'max_value' is a shared variable, 49 threads will enter the if-statements block, and they will try to update the 'max_value' one at a time using locks. But the order of executions among 49 threads is not defined, and therefore some threads may overwrite the actual maximum value to smaller values. You would need to compare the maximum value again within the critical section.

Answer (score 1):

Max is a 'reduction' - check out the Reduction sample in the SDK, and do max instead of summation.

The white paper's a little old but still reasonably useful:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1_1/Website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

The final optimization step is to use 'warp synchronous' coding to avoid unnecessary __syncthreads() calls.

It requires at least 2 kernel invocations - one to write a bunch of intermediate max() values to global memory, then another to take the max() of that array.

If you want to do it in a single kernel invocation, check out the threadfenceReduction SDK sample.  That uses __threadfence() and atomicAdd() to track progress, then has 1 block do a final reduction when all blocks have finished writing their intermediate results.

Answer (score -1):

There are different accesses for variables. when you define a variable by **device** then the variable is placed on GPU global memory and it is accessible by all threads in grid ,  **shared** places the variable in block shared memory and it is accessible only by the threads of that block , at the end if you don't use any keyword like  ***float max_value*** then the variable is placed on thread registers and it can be accessed only in that thread.In your code each thread have local variable max_value and it doesn't identify variables in other threads.